# MySQL server wont start through MySQL Workbench. gives ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, osx-yosemite, mysql-error-1064

As I am starting MySQLserver from MySQL workbench i get this :

```
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Starting server...
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Executing '/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start'
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Start server: Starting MySQL

2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Start server: .
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Start server: .
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Start server: .
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Start server: .
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Start server: .
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Start server: .
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Start server: .
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Start server: .
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Start server: .
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Start server: .
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Start server: ........................................
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Start server: .................................................. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/tatianaeliksmbp.pid).

2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Server start done.
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Checking server status...
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) (2003)
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Assuming server is not running
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Checking server status...
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) (2003)
2015-09-26 14:07:40 - Assuming server is not running
```

How do I fix this? and make it start correctly?

Comment: This question may be better suited for https://serverfault.com as it is more about server configuration than programming.

Comment: Why did you tagged with `SQL Server` when the question is related to `MySQL`?

Comment: Check the error.log, it should be in /var/lib/mysql/`hostname`.err or /usr/local/mysql/data/`hostname`.err depending upon the distribution. You can also check if you have log-error in my.cnf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tati, you didn't say in your question you are on OSX. You did not specifiy the server version, either. Without such info it's difficult to give you proper answers. If it was a 5.7 (pre-GA) server I could have told you that there was a bug that caused the server to start on port 3307 instead of 3306 (on OSX there is no my.cnf by default). Easily solvable by creating a config file with the explicit port setting.

Also, if you are only interested in a MySQL server, installing XAMPP is total overkill (because you already have an Apache server + python (not so much php) on your box). Instead I recommend to use [MySQL Sandbox](http://mysqlsandbox.net/) which allows to easily install a server whereever you want it (usually your home dir), install multiple servers or even replication groups and other complex setup (probably most interesting for developers).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by installing XAMPP, turns out installing MySQL server on MAC Yosemite is just a buggie option (And I have tried all fixes listed online to solve it). with XAMPP everything worked like a charm.